# java - Как работает рандом?

Tags: java

```
Random.nextInt(100);
```

Вроде обычный код, правда? Ну, берет этот рандом число от 0 до 100 и фиг с ним. А вы задумывались как он работает? Если нет последовательности, тогда что скрывается за этим методом, `nextInt`? Это секрет или всем давно известно, а я самый такой отсталый? Кто в теме, просвятите меня, пожалуйста. Интересно, не могу.

Comment: Зачем задумываться и какой может быть секрет , когда есть [исходный код](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Random.java) класса Random

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я не знаю, как конкретно это реализовано в Java, но вообще-то методы генерации случайных чисел, конечно, не секрет. Для начала берется из системы какое-нибудь быстро меняющееся значение или комбинация таких значений (напр. текущее время в миллисекундах `xor` объем свободной памяти в байтах), от нее считается какая-нибудь быстрая хэш-функция и полученный результат используется как основание (seed) для генерации псевдослучайной последовательности. Самый простой способ ее вычисления такой: `rand[i] = (rand[i - 1] * a + b) % c`, где `a, b` и `c` - специально подобранные достаточно большие числа. 
Вроде бы, современные процессоры это на аппаратном уровне умеют делать. 
См. более подробно на википедии:  [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Генератор_псевдослучайных_чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB)